# Trouble using javascript partial.lenses to obtain properties within an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, partial-lenses

I'm trying to figure out how to create a lens that'll give me an array of the key values from within an array. Here's a simple example:

```
const L = require('partial.lenses');

const data = [
  {
    r: [
      {
        d: {
          one: 1,
          two: 2
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    r: [
      {
        d: {
          three: 3,
          four: 4
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

const lens = L.compose (
  L.elems,
  L.prop ('r'),
  L.elems,
  L.prop ('d'),
);

const result = L.get (lens, data);
console.log (result);
```

I want:

```
[{ one: 1, two: 2 }, { three: 3, four: 4 }]
```

But get:

```
{ one: 1, two: 2 }
```

I'm sure this is trivial, but can't get it quite right. Once my lens correctly selects the array of 'd's I want to use L.modify to get the data with all of the 'd' objects replaced with a string.  I think I know how to do once my lens is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `L.collect` instead of `L.get` https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses#l-collect

Comment: Ohh wow, that works.  Thanks, if you want to answer the question with that I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `L.collect` instead of `L.get`, `L.get` returns the first found entity, while `L.collect` returns all matching entities, similar to `[].filter` vs `[].find`.

https://github.com/calmm-js/partial.lenses#l-collect